# Understanding "Gay-Lussac's law of Gaseous volumes/combining volumes"

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

Understanding "Gay-Lussac's law of Gaseous volumes/combining volumes". So I was reading Wikipedia and stumble across [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay-Lussac%27s_law#Law_of_combining_volumes). It defines it as follows "The ratio between the volumes of the reactant gases and the gaseous products can be expressed in simple whole numbers" and then give an example of 
$$\ce{2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O}$$ 
The problem is that example does not fit the definition. The volume of reactants is $3x$ where $x$ is a variable. The volume of product is $2x$. The ratio is $\frac 3 2$, which is not a whole number. Clearly, something is wrong here or something is wrong with me. Either way, can anyone help?

Comment: Instead of "ratio as a whole number" should be "ratio of whole numbers"

Comment: Or, mathematically, it is a rational number.

Comment: @Poutnik  Should I edit the Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ratio between the volumes of the reactant gases and the gaseous products can be **expressed in simple whole numbers**

Wikipedia is correct.

Expressed in, not expressed as.

$3/2$ can be expressed in simple whole numbers $3$ and $2$.